# Change to horizontal orientation for Seaborn `histplot()`

Tags: seaborn

How can I use `sns.histplot` to create a bar histogram where the bars are oriented horizontally instead of vertically (the default) and the labels are on the vertical axis?

Comment: You didn't add any code, so we don't know how you're calling `histplot`.  Usually you can just change `x=` to `y=`.  Just have a look at the examples at the [official doc page](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html).

Comment: All I had to do was set `y=` instead of `x=` and it worked! I read the official documentation but doing that was not clear to me from reading it.

Comment: @reckoner not being rude, but genuinely curious how you missed the second example in the [histplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html) docs, which demonstrate this. was there somewhere else you were looking that seemed more like the natural place to look for the information?

Comment: @mwaskom To me, it isn't immediately obvious if you're not using a dataframe (e.g. a Numpy array as the `data` argument). Specifically that data is not a required parameter - it defaults to `None` but it doesn't explicitly say optional or that you can provide `data` and/or `x` and/or `y`. It's technically in the function signature but there are no documented examples using vectors as input.